# Graph Isomorphism algorithm that doesn't always work

Tags: algorithms, spectral-graph-theory

I just thought of the following incomplete algorithm for deciding whether two graphs are isomorphic:

Let $A$ and $A'$ be adjacency matrices of two graphs. Then for some unitary $U,U’$ and diagonals $D,D’$ (in which the diagonals are sorted) we have:

$U^tAU=D$ and $U’^tA’U’=D’$.

If $D \neq D'$, the graphs are not isomorphic.

If $D=D’$, then for $V=UU'^t$, we have:

$V^tAV=A’$.

If $V$ is a permutation matrix, then the graphs are isomorphic. If not, then the graphs may or may not be isomorphic.

Is there an easy way to fix the incomplete part of the algorithm? If so, then please explain how. If not, then please explain why not.

Addendum: The problem is when the graph has lots of repeated eigenvalues. Then $V$ will not necessarily be a permutation matrix and converting it into a permutation matrix which satisfies the equation $V^tAV=A'$ seems to be hard.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? Of course, nobody will be able to give an *efficient* way to fix this algorithm, and we don't know if the graph isomorphism problem is "difficult", from the complexity point of view. I don't think this question is answerable in the actual form. Would you mind tell us more about your expectations for the answer?

Comment: I am looking for an answer which explains why this approach is problematic, if it is problematic, or fixes the problem, if possible.

Comment: @FPE, I just edited it, making my question clearer.

Comment: The problem is when the eigenvalues are not all distinct. Then it is possible that $V$ is not a permutation matrix, even if the graphs are isomorphic.

Comment: But even when the eigenvalues are not all distinct and $V$ is not a permutation matrix, isn't it possible to turn $V$ into a permutation matrix when the graphs are isomorphic?

Comment: I think it would be better for your addendum to be as an edit to your question, not as an "answer", which is not exactly *answering* the question. Still, my point is the same. If someone comes up with an algorithm in $n^n$ to the problem and asks how to fix it, there is not really an answer to this. Your question is the same: you come up with an attempt to an algorithm, and finding a "fix" to it would solve a long-standing problem of the community.

Comment: I added my answer as an edit and deleted my answer.

Comment: Maybe you should post this on [cstheory.se]? This is the site that hosts research related problems in computer science. I think that you can't get a definitive answer here or on [cs.se]!

Comment: I've gotten good answers here before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the adjacency matrices of two graphs are similar, the graphs are said to be cospectral (and there is a large literature on the topic). Basically you are asking how to solve the graph isomorphism problem when your inputs are cospectral. No method for graph isomorphism is known that can make effective use of cospectrality.

Since we can decide in polynomial time if two graphs are cospectral, and since we have not been able to solve graph isomorphism in polynomial time, I do no think there will be any simple way to complete your "algorithm".

It is known that if we consider graphs where the multiplicity of any eigenvalue is at most $m$, then graph isomorphism can be solved in polynomial time.